# Checkbox at top of drop down

Tags: css

I need a drop down at top of which there is a check box.
Both check box and dropdown has their own functionally
Like image added[image: dropdown like this]

I think tried with margin-top: -5 at check box but didn't work.

How to do this

Comment: From where I get code for this ???
This single line man

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you!

```js
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();
      
   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
But What  I Need is that a check box ontop of dropdown
On click at check box all rows are selected while on click at dropdown there are separate options.
What you provided always give to chose from options whereever we click